# What is the correct notation if two random variables belong to the same distribution?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, notation

I want to explain that both the real and imaginary part of a complex variable follow a zero-mean complex Gaussian distribution. How can I write that?

For one variable I'd write
$a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

But for two? Maybe
$\{a,b\} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$?

What's the correct notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen a notational standard for this in any of my courses.  As long as you define your notation or make it really obvious what you mean, I think you'll be fine.  I personally write it as $$x, y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$

and haven't had any problems with my professors.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has an answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution

They notate the fact that two random variables $X,Y$ are "equal in distribution" by $X \stackrel{d}{=} Y$.

I have no idea how common this notation is. Also note that the mere fact could also be called *identically distributed*, as "*i.d*".

Comment: Maybe my question was mistakable: I don't want to know how to talk about equality in distribution, I want to write it in a simple one-liner formula that declares the distribution and explains the fact that both variables belong to this distribution at the very same time.

Comment: @Michael Then I would simply write $a,b \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Wouldn't you also write $a,b \in M$?

Answer (score 1):

You could write

$$ (a,b)^T \sim \mathcal{N}_2(\mathbf{0},\sigma^2\mathbf{I}) $$

to indicate that the vector of random variables $\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix} $ belongs to the multivariate normal distribution of dimension 2 with zero mean vector $\mathbf{0}$, and where $a$ and $b$ are independent and each have variance $\sigma^2$.

This seems a bit indirect though. You might be better off saying it in words as per http://everything2.com/title/complex+Gaussian+distribution. I.e. something like "the complex number $a+ib$ follows a two-dimensional uncorrelated Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance per real dimension of $\sigma^2$".