# What does capital D above an equal sign mean?

Tags: time-series, self-study, notation

I was beginning to self study time series and came across this notation: $\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}$. I wonder what it means? (I have limited access to the textbooks for the moment, so I have to post a question here.)

For more context, it was in the definition for a strongly stationary sequence, where the article states the condition for such a sequence being $(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_k})\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}(X_{t_1+h},...,X_{t_k+h})$ for all $\{t_1,...,t_k\}$ and $h$.

Comment: Where did you find this  notation?

Comment: equality in distribution

Comment: @Sycorax http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/timeseries/t.pdf page 1.

Comment: @JoeShmo Thanks! It makes sense.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111023/what-is-the-correct-notation-if-two-random-variables-belong-to-the-same-distribu/111026#111026 discusses the same notation (but with a lowercase d) and links to the relevant wikipedia page. I am pretty sure there are several other related questions on site.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for pointing that out. The only problem is, for those people like me who didn't know the meaning of this notation, the search engine is not likely to lead them there. Typing in something like "equal sign with capital d" is to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the linked notes, the symbol refers to [equality in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution) ---i.e., the statement:

$$(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_k})\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}(X_{t_1+h},...,X_{t_k+h})
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } t_1,...,t_k \text{ and } h,$$

is a shorthand way of saying that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1},...,X_{t_k} \leqslant \mathbf{x}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1+h},...,X_{t_k+h} \leqslant \mathbf{x})
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } t_1,...,t_k, h \text{ and } \mathbf{x}.$$